# attach a client certificate through code when connecting to an OData service

Tags: c#, ssl, client, ssl-certificate, odata

Am trying to query an odata web.api hosted on IIS7. The site requires a client cert. How do I attach the certificate to the query? Using web.api 2, framework 4.5, mvc5

```
string certPath = @"E:\ClientCertificate.cer";

Uri uri = new Uri("https://server/odata/"); 
var container = new CourseService.Container(uri);
container.ClientCertificate = new X509Certificate(certPath);
```

The extension to the container class was achieved by reading this: 
[http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/odata-attach-client-certificate-through.htm](http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/odata-attach-client-certificate-through.html)

Comment: In debug the Client certificate for container is null, it doesn't seem to attach...

Comment: Hamlet, thanks for edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach the certificate to request in SendRequest2 event yourself:

```
    context.SendingRequest2 += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            // We can safely cast RequestMessage to HttpWebRequestMessage if this is not in batch.
            if (!eventArgs.IsBatchPart)
            {
                ((HttpWebRequestMessage)eventArgs.RequestMessage).HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(theCertificate);
            }
        };
```